# Apache FOP PDF not showing Persian font correctly

Tags: apache-fop, moqui

I want to try to use an Apache FOP for printing Persian language PDF, but the PDF font does not display properly.
In fact, the letters appear in reverse and apart. Anyone can help?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question. Good luck!

Comment: Which version of FOP are you using?

Comment: It would be better if you could [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51017187/edit) the question to include a **minimal FO file** that can be used to reproduce the problem and test a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apache OFBiz I have used the  Google NotoSans font which is Apache licensed 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-5917

You can see it in action at bottom of PDF there (credential admin/ofbiz): https://demo-trunk.ofbiz.apache.org/example/control/fonts.pdf

It should work for Persian language I guess, did not test.

Comment: thanks for reply JacquesLeRoux.I will test it. but i thinks this font is not for persian font.

Comment: You can try the same way than I did with a font supporting Persian :)